# Use Regex with Python to get an specifc part of the iframe src

Tags: python, regex, iframe

I try to capture an iframe src content that I want to change. I don't have direct access to the HTML, I get it HTML from an API.

You can see some iframe example below:

```
<iframe src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490">
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="276" mozallowfullscreen="" scrolling="no" src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/%20f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490"></iframe>
```

I have many other type of iframe examples, the only part they have in common is this part of src content **https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302**

I create the following code to find an element:

```
// some code
regex_page_embed = r"http.?://fast\.player\.liquidplatform\.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/*"
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
page_elements = list(soup.children)
for element in page_elements:
    try:
        s1 = re.search(regex_page_embed, str(element))
        if s1:
            print(s1)
            print(s1.group())
```

After that I create more code that I can use and effectively change the HTML using the API, I don't think is necessary to put it here.
But when I use:

```
print(s1)
print(s1.group())
```

I got the following result:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(686, 771), match='https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/emb>
https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(126, 211), match='https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/emb>
https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(686, 771), match='https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/emb>
https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(227, 312), match='https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/emb>
https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/
```

I want to get the last part of the iframe src content. In the example below

```
<iframe src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490">
```

The **f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977** is the part that I want.

**print(s1)** and **print(s1.group())** don't show the last part of the src content, how can I get the last part of the iframe src content?

Comment: In the regex, change the star at the end to `(.*?)(?=\")`.

Comment: Relevant read on parsing html content with regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/9183344

Comment: I'd just use `bs4` to parse the iframe and then extract the `src` text content and go from there...

Comment: I try to use bs4 first to get the content, but I see that I get more results with regex than bs4. I investigate why this is happening and I find that some iframes are inserted in the page using javascript document.write. This way only regex was able to find it, bs4 can't find it as well.

Comment: Ah right, since it's dynamic contents you should be using a different module like `selenium` or `requests-html`.  I'm actually surprised you are able to get the iframe in the `bs4` extracted content at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better regex for capturing the whole url while having any optional content between `<iframe` tag and `src` tag is this,

```
<iframe .*?\bsrc="(https?://fast\.player\.liquidplatform\.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/[^"]+)
```

Match using this regex and capture your url from group1.

**[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zSmcG0/1)**

Here is your updated Python code,

```
regex_page_embed = r'<iframe .*?\bsrc="(https?://fast\.player\.liquidplatform\.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/[^"]+)'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
page_elements = list(soup.children)
for element in page_elements:
    try:
        s1 = re.search(regex_page_embed, str(element))
        if s1:
            print(s1.group(1)) # extract url using first group
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `r'<iframe src="[^"]*/([^"]+)"'` as the pattern for your search.

**Example:**

```py
>>> text = """<iframe src="https://fast.player.liquidplatform.com/pApiv2/embed/e50a2b66dc19adc532f288eb4bf2d302/f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977" webkitallowfullscreen="" width="490">"""
>>> pat = r'<iframe src="[^"]*/([^"]+)"'
>>> search = re.search(pat, text)
>>> search[1]
'f2c5f6ca3a4610c55d70cb211ef9d977'
>>>
```

Comment: I edit my question now, I include a second iframe example. I forgot to mention that I have another type of iframes include in the HTML. Your answer will be correct if all iframes are only based in the first iframe example. I have another iframe examples in my page that are completely different from the 2 examples that I provide, the only common part is the iframe src content.